# Find string and then copy cell immediately to its right

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an Excel workbook that has a Get Data from a webpage. This webpage apparently changes and the field I need to copy moves. I'd like to be able to search the column I'm in (A row 1) down for the word Xbox. Then have the box in Column B = the amount adjacent to that word.

So code would be something like:

A1=Find Xbox;=Found
B1=Find box adjacent to Xbox; =Found

```
        A                B
R1    Found and=Xbox  Found and =9000
R2
R3    Menu            Blank
R4    Login/Register  Blank
R5    home            Blank
R6    xbox            9000
R7    PS3             8000
R8    PC              6000
```

Comment: Have you tried using `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: ^^ yes VLookup is one of the most useful functions in Excel.  Learn it, Love it, but dont have its babies.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically:

```
=VLOOKUP("Xbox",A:B,2,0)
```